# remove whitespace between multiple radio box

Tags: twig

I add multi radio box in `twig` page like this:

```
      <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="avatar-1" type="radio" name="avatar" value="1" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-1" for="avatar-1"></label>
        <input id="avatar-2" type="radio" name="avatar" value="2" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-2" for="avatar-2"></label>
        <input id="avatar-3" type="radio" name="avatar" value="3" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-3" for="avatar-3"></label>
        <input id="avatar-4" type="radio" name="avatar" value="4" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-4" for="avatar-4"></label>
        <input id="avatar-5" type="radio" name="avatar" value="5" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-5" for="avatar-5"></label>
        <input id="avatar-6" type="radio" name="avatar" value="6" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-6" for="avatar-6"></label>
      </div>
```

in Output in see `whitespace`:

[image]

how do can i remove `whitespace` in `twig` template?!

Comment: Which twig version and PHP version? Also why is this bothering u?

Comment: @DarkBee: 7.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [spaceless filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/spaceless.html). It will do exactly what you want : removing whitespace **between** HTML elements only (keeping the ones inside).

Using this in Twig :

```html
{% apply spaceless %}
    <div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="avatar-1" type="radio" name="avatar" value="1" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-1" for="avatar-1"></label>
        <input id="avatar-2" type="radio" name="avatar" value="2" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-2" for="avatar-2"></label>
        <input id="avatar-3" type="radio" name="avatar" value="3" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-3" for="avatar-3"></label>
        <input id="avatar-4" type="radio" name="avatar" value="4" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-4" for="avatar-4"></label>
        <input id="avatar-5" type="radio" name="avatar" value="5" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-5" for="avatar-5"></label>
        <input id="avatar-6" type="radio" name="avatar" value="6" />
        <label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-6" for="avatar-6"></label>
    </div>
{% endapply %}
```

Will give this HTML :

```html
<div class="cc-selector"><input id="avatar-1" type="radio" name="avatar" value="1" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-1" for="avatar-1"></label><input id="avatar-2" type="radio" name="avatar" value="2" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-2" for="avatar-2"></label><input id="avatar-3" type="radio" name="avatar" value="3" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-3" for="avatar-3"></label><input id="avatar-4" type="radio" name="avatar" value="4" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-4" for="avatar-4"></label><input id="avatar-5" type="radio" name="avatar" value="5" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-5" for="avatar-5"></label><input id="avatar-6" type="radio" name="avatar" value="6" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-6" for="avatar-6"></label></div>
```

Comment: with `apply spaceless` i see this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected "apply" tag (expecting closing tag for the "if" tag defined near line 164)`. i change `apply spaceless` to `spaceless` and this worked now

Comment: In older version of twig you need to use the spaceless tag instead : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the contents of the template is HTML I'd advise you to use SeeoX's approach.

But I've decided to mention the other option to assign the contents of a template to a variable and apply filters which could be useful sometimes:

```
{% set contents %}
    {% include ('cc-selector.twig') %}
{% endset %}

contents spaceless:
{{ contents | spaceless }}

replace only new lines:
{{ contents | replace({"\n": ""}) | raw }}
```

[working example](https://twigfiddle.com/jns56v)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the linebreak between the input & the label. Removing that space may/may not help, but try that.

```html
<div class="cc-selector">
        <input id="avatar-1" type="radio" name="avatar" value="1" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-1" for="avatar-1"></label><input id="avatar-2" type="radio" name="avatar" value="2" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-2" for="avatar-2"></label><input id="avatar-3" type="radio" name="avatar" value="3" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-3" for="avatar-3"></label><input id="avatar-4" type="radio" name="avatar" value="4" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-4" for="avatar-4"></label><input id="avatar-5" type="radio" name="avatar" value="5" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-5" for="avatar-5"></label><input id="avatar-6" type="radio" name="avatar" value="6" /><label class="drinkcard-cc avatar-6" for="avatar-6"></label>
</div>
```